# Loading MKMapKit overlay tiles from server

Tags: ios, gdal, mapkit, overlays

The Apple sample code TileMap is great at showing how to add raster image overlays using gdal2tiles, but it depends on having the tile directory on the device. What is the best way to  adapt the code to load the files from the web?

I noticed that one of the first thing it does is enumerate through the directory structure of the tiles folder to find out the available tiles. Is there a similar way to do this directory enumeration for a remote server?

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could start with the [Open Street Map iOS page](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Apple_iOS), which links to some libraries.

[Route Me](https://github.com/route-me/route-me) is an open-source replacement for a MapView. Not quite what you're looking for, but you might be able to grab the network code and use it.

Let's Do It World has some sample code, with [instructions here](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/OSM_in_MapKit).